# UIWebView not playing embedded stream mp4 video

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, mp4

I am trying to play a video from a website that I load inside my UIWebView in an iOS application developed with Objective C language.

When I hit the play button, I get an error message :

> The video cannot be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

The code I've written for the web view is quite simple :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webSite];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webBrowser loadRequest:request];
```

The thing is that the same video is loading fine on Safari from the same device (iPad ).

Thanks!

Comment: pls share your url link i hope it may be not load in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The video is not a web site. You might need to wrap it to a web page.
(2) If the video URL is not „https://„ it will fail playing since ios9 (?). You need to enable „Arbitrary Loads“ in your App‘s Info.plist.

Advice: Check option 2 first.

Comment: HI and thanks for your answer. The URL is https. I tried adding the Arbitrary Loads and it seems to do the same thing. The URL is embedded in the web page, I think they have a javascript function that maybe blocks the request.

Comment: Strange thing. Are you testing on your iPad? Maybe you could try a WKWebView instead the UIWebView.